# php ftp_put does not work

Tags: php, ftp, put

I can't understand why this code can't work:

```
// connect and login to FTP server
$ftp_server = "domain.com";
$ftp_conn = ftp_connect($ftp_server) or die("Could not connect to $ftp_server");
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'php@domain.com', 'password')or die ("Error  Login");

$or = "/TestUpload.txt";
$dest = 'TestUpload.txt';


// upload file
ftp_put($ftp_conn, $dest, $or, FTP_ASCII) or die("Errore di upload!");


// close connection
ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

Does the dest file path is not true? 
I wnat to upload thefile in the public_html directory, this is the start directory of the ftp account. 
The file i want to upload is in the same directory of the php script, 
the error i get is in the ftp put function, 
can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Are you try remove [/] in $or var?

Comment: yes i try to remove / in $or var but nothing....

Comment: How can i get errors of ftp put?